# How long is the heartbeat interval of SCTP in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, sctp

WebRTC DataChannels use SCTP. Looking at the graph of bits received from `chrome://webrtc-internals`, there is a regular sending of a small amount of data. Is this the SCTP heartbeat?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, this is the [ICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment) heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

I am just elaborating Sam's answer.

WebRTC DataChannel uses Stream Control Transport Protocol (SCTP) for sending
 and receiving arbitrary data. Since, WebRTC requires that all WebRTC traffic be
 encrypted, DTLS is used. However, most routers and NAT devices don't handle this
 protocol well. Hence, SCTP is tunneled over DTLS and UDP. Now, even when two 
 peers are exchanging arbitrary data, it is happening over UDP. Hence, I too 
 believe that it is not a SCTP heartbeat.

As you might know, RTCPeerConnection uses ICE for resolving connectivity issues between
 peers. ICE uses STUN keep-alives to check the connectivity status between 
 the peers. Currently, I believe chrome sends out STUN Binding Request every [450 ms](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/pnRYbD3-r78) to perform connectivity checks, but there is an ongoing discussion on extending that time interval.

Answer (score 1):

ICE's STUN/TURN binding request / response messages are not in any way related to SCTP heartbeat messaging. It is my understanding that the chrome internals does not register / display the heartbeat send or receive counts. I also realize this is a 10 year old question.